# Sending an email alert when query rows are more than 50K

Tags: batch

We have a apex job in which we are fetching some records(SOQL) in execute method based on the record values retured by start method. But, there are more than 50000 records corresponding to one particular value in an object. My requirement is to send an email alert from batch apex if records returned by SOQL are more than 50K. We know that limit exceptions cannot be handled through try/catch blocks in apex.

Is there any workaround to accomplish this? Please find below mentioned code:

```
global class BatchUpdateOptOutPermissions implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
    {

       /* Start - Variables */
       /* End - Variables */

       /* Start - Constructor */
       global BatchUpdateOptOutPermissions()
       {
            //Do Nothing
       }
       /* End - Constructor */

       global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
       {
          DateTime dtLast24Hours = System.now().addHours(-24);
          return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, Channel_Value__c FROM Brand_Permission__c WHERE Permission_Value__c = \'OUT\' AND LastModifiedDate >: dtLast24Hours');
       }

       global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
       {
            List<Brand_Permission__c> lstBP = (List<Brand_Permission__c>)scope;// Casting the scope to list of Brand_Permission__c.
            List<Brand_Permission__c> lstBPToUpdate = new List<Brand_Permission__c>();// List to hold the existing channel permission records which needs to updated.
            Set<String> setPermissionValues = new Set<String>();// Set to hold the channel permission values corresponding to those permissions that are passed from the batch.

            //Iterating to hold the channel values
            for(Brand_Permission__c objBP : lstBP)
            {
                if(String.isNotEmpty(objBP.Channel_Value__c))
                    setPermissionValues.add(objBP.Channel_Value__c);
            }

            if(!setPermissionValues.isEmpty())
            {
                //Fetching the existing permissions which are not opted out in last 24 hours.
                for(Brand_Permission__c objBP : [SELECT ID FROM Brand_Permission__c WHERE Permission_Value__c != 'OUT' AND Channel_Value__c IN : setPermissionValues])
                {
                    lstBPToUpdate.add(new Brand_Permission__c(Id = objBP.Id, Source_Time_Stamp__c = System.now(), Effective_Date__c = System.now(), Permission_Value__c = 'OUT', Source_Application__c = 'SharedOptOutSource'));
                }
            }

           Database.update(lstBPToUpdate,false);
       }

       global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
       {
            //Do Nothing
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to try add "LIMIT 50000" statement in SOQL, and if that is returning 50 000 records -- send email alert. But I would suggest instead of 50 000 use getLimitQueryRows()-getQueryRows(), to ensure that there are no exception appeared

Comment: @kurunve you should post that as an answer, I just wanted to post that myself.

Comment: Isn't the limit in batch apex 50,000,000 rather than 50,000? You should get no exception for 50,000.

Comment: @PhilHawthorn I didn't know about that exception. I do know that you get 200 queries in an asynchronous context. Do you have a link to the documentation where that is stated?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what are you going to do when you receive such an email?

Comment: For QueryLocator limit is 50 million records. [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) So there is no need to worry about that but for the SOQL in execute method you can put 50000 limit.